# I am trying to run Ubuntu mkhomedir_helper from python, it is failing

Tags: python, subprocess

First, let me say thank you for taking the time to read this question.  I have been searching for an answer to this for hours, and I keep coming up empty handed.

I am very new to Python, so, be gentle.  I am writing a script that I can run with cron that will attach to an LDAP server, query for usernames, and then use the Ubuntu "mkhomedir_helper" command to create home directories for users that don't currently have one.  I have the entire script working except for the specific part of running the "mkhomedir_helper" command.  I have tried using the os.open function as well as the subprocess function.  I have read everything I can find, and it all says pretty much to do it the same way.  However, this command REFUSES to run in that manner.  I can replace it with "echo" or "ls" and the command runs as expected.

I am executing the script as the "root" user, so it shouldn't be a file permissions issue.  Any suggestions on a resolution would be nice.

```
uid = entry[1]['uid'][0]
    #print uid
    homeDir = "/home/"+(uid)
    if not os.path.isdir(homeDir):
        subprocess.call(['mkhomedir_helper', homeDir])
```

Comment: I would expect it has to do with needing elevated permissions to run the script and so you need to run it as `sudo`.

Comment: what exactly is happening?

Comment: DrCord, I tried adding "sudo" to the front of the command, and nothing.  Padraic, absolutely nothing is happening, the script exits without error and the folders are not created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite this being 7 months old I thought I would post in case others run across it.

The argument to `mkhomedir_helper` must be a log-in ID not a path.

All the details are [right there in the `mkhomedir_helper` man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/8/mkhomedir_helper/).

Now if I can just figure out why `mkhomedir_helper` copies some but not all of the skeleton directory contents when run via cron (running from the command line works just fine).

Comment: Thanks for finding this and answering the question.  I see now where I messed up, even though eventually I went a completely different way to achieve my goal.